# How to identify specific IE window in blueprism when more than one window has the same title

Tags: blueprism

I am trying to identify a particular IE window and attach to it using blueprism.

My issue is that I will have more than 1 window with the same title and blueprism is not able to identify and attach to it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

When you set up your Attach page in your object, you'll have to include a loop which increments a Data Item set up for the `Child Index` property of the Attach action within your Navigate stage which does the actual attaching.

You'll then have to add logic to verify that a particular element/elements unique to the target instance are present in the attached version. If not, detach and increment your `Child Index` property until you find the right one.